# Datepicker jquery dosen't return the correct date

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to user the datepicker jquery but I have a problem : [image: view image here]

When I select the first day I can choose (in this example, the 17th) it works fine, and in my database it inserts the correct date.
But when I select 18th or above for a date, it dosen't work and it return the following date, and I don't know why : 1970-01-01

Here's my code :

```
<input type="text" id="datepickerGo" name="datepickerGo" class="datepicker form-control"  placeholder="Selectionez une date" required>

$(function(){

    $('.datepicker').datepicker({

        dateFormat : 'dd/mm/yy',
        minDate : 0, // 0 permet de ne pas sélectionner les jours déjà passés.
        maxDate : 360,
        onSelect: function(date){

            var option;

            if(this.id == "datepickerGo"){ // si je suis sur l'idée de l'allée :

                option = 'minDate';

                } else {
                    option 
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: can u add the whole code here to know the library which you are using for datepicker, it could help to give solution faster.

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve in the if/else block? the else is returning var option, and the if is returning the word 'minDate'. Do a console.log and test what date is being selected before worrying about passing to server and adding to database. First: check on browser, then on server and then on database.

Comment: @BathriNathan I'm using this : <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: @NawedKhan i've forgot to delete the if/else block, it was for another thing. I've console.log the value and it returns the correct date, but when inserted in the databse it's 01 01 1970

Comment: @RahulRaut it doesnt change anything

Comment: if console shows the correct date then the issue is not client side. Your server side code is changing the date. It is not a JQuery question. I don't know what server side tech your are using.

Comment: I'm using mysql and here is a screen of the database : https://ibb.co/LJkGg1x